# AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction background Color using UIImage?

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

```
I want to change the background color for AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction which is working fine.But in when I am using UIImage for Color Pattern its not Working ??? Please Help...here is code Image Using.also I am giving is BackgroundColor White but its not Showing it White.
```

here is my code I am using:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *MainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction]; 
    MainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration);   
    MainInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructionsArr;
    UIColor  *bgBlurrcolor =[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aa.png"]];
    MainInstruction.backgroundColor = bgBlurrcolor.CGColor;
```

Comment: Hey Vikesh, Did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Check these links

Only solid BGRA colors are supported; patterns and other supported colors are ignored. If the rendered pixel buffer does not have alpha, the alpha value of the background color is ignored.
If the background color is NULL, the video compositor uses a default background color of opaque black.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocompositioninstruction?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocompositioninstruction/1389384-backgroundcolor?language=objc